# Windows 7 Screensaver only works on 4 out of 5 monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, screensaver

I have 5 monitors. When the windows screensaver turns on it only covers the right 4 screens (even when previewing). Windows and background remain visible on the left most monitor. I'm using the built-in Ribbons screensaver, although it happen with the other built in screensavers except for Blank. Does anyone else have this problem? Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you use one of these screen savers? http://www.reallyslick.com/screensavers/  They look and run well on multi monitor setups. Window 7 screen saversdonot work well on multi monitor hosts...I personally like flocks and I use it on 3 & 4 monitor setups

Comment: Are you using any other applications to control monitor functions such as [link](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)? Any external application in regards to the OS will override/alter the way the monitors perform as a whole.

Comment: I'm not using any special multi monitor software. I'm a minimalist when it comes to running stuff in the background. I'm not interested in running 3rd party screen savers. I'm trying to find out if anyone who has 5 screens can run the built in screen savers on all five screens. Thanks.